# Stuck with an IF condition with two variables

Tags: jquery, if-statement, scroll

I'm trying to change an image multple times on my webpage for different sections, but I'm stuck maybe in a simple solution.

Here is my jquery for this issue. The idea is to change the image between 1200 and 1900 and then change it again between 2500 and 3500.

Please somebody help me out!!

Thanks a lot.

```
var $logo = $("h6.navbar-brand-spacing > a");
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var e = $(this).scrollTop();
  if ((e > 1200 && e < 1900) && (e > 2500 && e < 3500)) {
    $logo.addClass('navbar-brand-scroll');
  } else {
    $logo.removeClass('navbar-brand-scroll');
  }
});
```

Comment: Also found a solution with the else if statement.
Thanks to all for your help and answers!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
var $logo = $("h6.navbar-brand-spacing > a");
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var e = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ((e > 1200 && e < 1900) || (e > 2500 && e < 3500)) {
      $logo.addClass('navbar-brand-scroll');
    } else {
        $logo.removeClass('navbar-brand-scroll');
    }
});
```

Put OR(||) in between `e > 1200 && e < 1900` and `e > 2500 && e < 3500`, which means execute the inside if code for any of the conditions.

If you put AND(&&) then `e > 1200 && e < 1900` and `e > 2500 && e < 3500` both can not be true at a time so it always returns false.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It properly works!!

I also found another solution with the else if statement but yours is simple and easy.

Best regards!!

Answer (score 0):

You're using `&&` between the 2 conditions, which will never happen.

`if ((e > 1200 && e < 1900) && (e > 2500 && e > 3500))`

It can NEVER be both between 1200-1900 AND > 2500 ... 
Use OR instead:

`if ((e > 1200 && e < 1900) || (e > 2500 && e < 3500))`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It properly works!!

I also found another solution with the else if statement but yours is simple and easy.

Best regards!!

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a bit dodgy

```
  if ((e > 1200 && e < 1900) && (e > 2500 && e > 3500))
```

Says if `e` is between 1200 and 1900 and also greater than 2500 and greater than 3500 and therefore always evaluates to false.

Change it to

```
  if ((e > 1200 && e < 1900) || (e > 2500 && e < 3500))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It properly works!!

I also found another solution with the else if statement but yours is simple and easy.

Best regards!!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a logical problem in your if statement. It says that if the variable "e" is between 1200 and 1900 and at the same time between 2500 and 3500 so I think that you are in a loop in else statement.

Comment: You're right!! Sometimes the easiest and obvious answers are not as that!! lol.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((e > 1200 && e < 1900) || (e > 2500 && e > 3500)) {
// if e is great of 1200 and less 1900
// OR
// e is great 2500 and less 3500
    $logo.addClass('navbar-brand-scroll');
} else {
// if e is lower 1200 OR greater 1900 but lower than 2500 
// OR greater than 3500
    $logo.removeClass('navbar-brand-scroll');
}
```

Ist this it ? **||** instead **&&** between conditions

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It properly works!!

I also found another solution with the else if statement but yours is simple and easy.

Best regards!!